# What is the best calendar plugin for a website?

Tags: php, jquery

I am needing to make a calendar feature for my website... This feature will allow the user to make a todo on certain dates. I want it to work similar to ical where you can click on a date and add to-dos... and for those to dos to be saved next time the user logs in.. If i could just get a starting point on where to look for this I would be grateful.

Comment: Fullcalender is pretty good: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

reference:http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
It is very efficient.